# wrap AJAX in a jQuery function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to nest an AJAX request in a jQuery so I can put a time interval of 5 seconds.

The AJAX request does what it's supposed to do, but from the moment I try to nest it I keep getting the message:

> "jQuery.ajax is not a function"

How do I fix this - where do I make a mistake?

This is the (working) ajax request:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: "check.php",
        success: function(result) {
            var html = jQuery('<div>').html(result);

        var x = (html.find("div#a").html());
        console.log(x);
    }
});
```

this the nested code - which results in a jQuery.ajax is not a function error:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var row1 = "<?php echo $row_cnt; ?>";
    var interval = 1000; // 1000 = 1 second, 3000 = 3 seconds
    function doAjax() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "check.php",
            success: function(result) {
                var html = jQuery('<div>').html(result);

                var x = (html.find("div#a").html());
                console.log(x);
            }
        });
    }
    setInterval(doAjax, interval);

</script>
```

When I google the problem, I get a lot of answers about the "slim - jquery libary", but I use this one:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: probably working when replace `jQuery` with `$`  e.g `$.ajax({...`

Comment: Already tried this solution - not working ... Thanks

Comment: either you try to run the script before you loaded jquery or your jquerx version actually doesnt have the ajax wrappers included, i guess it might be the first though

Comment: your nested script tag muste be below the jquery source script tag

Comment: Maybe second but, I load jquery before I run the script ..

Comment: hmn but i looked into the src url and ajax seems to be included, are you using other libraries like motools? that might "stole" the $

Comment: I use the fontawesome libary https://kit.fontawesome.com/eb8014fe4a.js

Answer (score 0):

move this `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>`
up script with interval

Comment: Thanks Diego! But This line is up - offcourse, otherwise the (not nested) ajax code wouldn't work either ...

Comment: It is strange because if you copy that code in the console of this site that is made with jquery, it works fine, your code does not break before? can you try the cdn here?

Comment: I just downloaded the libary to the server - now it is loaded local.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help!
The problem was that lower down in the code I was still getting the slim libary - this had eluded my attention.

The problem is solved.